# QProcess read and write

Tags: qt, qprocess

I am trying to read and write from a qprocess right now. I made a little test program that takes input and redisplays it on the screen in a loop. Here is my code from Qt

```
  QString path = "./test";

        tcd = new QProcess(this);
        QStringList args;
        args << "";
        tcd->start(path,args);

        if(!tcd->waitForStarted(3000))
        {
            stdoutput->append("<h1><font color=red>There was a problem starting the software, please try running the program again.</font></h1>");

        }
        tcd->write("hello\n");
        tcd->write("hello\n");
        tcd->write("hello\n");
        tcd->write("hello\n");
        //tcd->write("quit\n");

QObject::connect(tcd, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput()), this, SLOT(appendTextBox()));
```

This won't work unless I send that last quit command (which terminates my test program).

Here's my read command:

```
void TCD2_GUI::appendTextBox(){
    stdoutput->append("new output available: \n");
    QByteArray newData = tcd->readAllStandardOutput();
    stdoutput->append(QString::fromLocal8Bit(newData));
}
```

if I send quit, I will get all the output from the program at once, including everything I have sent it.

What am I doing wrong here?

As per request, here is the code from the program:

```
int main(int argC[], char* argV[]){
    printf("Welcome!\n");
    char* input = malloc(160);
    gets(input);

    while(strcmp(input,"quit") != 0)
    {
        printf("Got input %s\n", input);
        gets(input);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the doc:

> Certain subclasses of QIODevice, such
>   as QTcpSocket and **QProcess**, are
>   asynchronous. This means that I/O
>   functions such as write() or read()
>   always return immediately, while
>   communication with the device itself
>   may happen when control goes back to
>   the event loop. **QIODevice provides
>   functions that allow you to force
>   these operations to be performed
>   immediately**, while blocking the
>   calling thread and without entering
>   the event loop.
>
> ...
>
> waitForBytesWritten() - This function
>   suspends operation in the calling
>   thread until one payload of data has
>   been written to the device.
>
> ...
>
> Calling these functions from the main,
>   GUI thread, may cause your user
>   interface to freeze.

[link](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qiodevice.html)

Comment: yeah but I am signal catching, so I don't think that should matter. But maybe I have a poor understanding of this. Regardless, I put a tcd->waitForBytesWritten(); in my code, and still nothing.. Edit: I have a button that sends input into my code, so it's after the signal is initiated, still nothing.